# Python - best way to programmatically add lines to .py files?

Tags: python

I have a project that involves creating a new class/model every week or so. Each time I create a new class, I have to do a bunch of initial steps, one of which is adding a reference to it to an existing .py file that looks like this -

```
from models.abc import AbcClass
from models.xyz import XyzClass

class SomeFactory:
@staticmethod
def create(template_id: str, **kwargs):
    match template_id.lower():
        case "abc":
            return AbcClass(**kwargs)
        case "xyz":
            return XyzClass(**kwargs)
        ...
```

Ideally, I would have a Python function that I can pass in variables such as the `template_id` and class name, and it would add another `case` statement plus the imports for me.

Are there any packages that can help with this? If not, I imagine I could read the .py file as a string and use regex to make my inserts but I was curious if there's another way.

Comment: You can do this with metaprogramming; you don't need code generation. Consider using a plugin-registration framework to let `AbcClass`, `XyzClass`, etc. register themselves somewhere you can look up all the models that exist. If they register themselves under the names `abc` and `xyz` that you later use as template IDs, then everything you need is right there in the plugin registry.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, sounds ideal. Do you have any recommendations for a lightweight framework library or a tutorial that you think would set me on the right course?

Comment: Oh, dear. I vaguely remember there being a plugin framework included with the Python standard library somewhere (recently-added, back then), but it's been a lot of years since I was a Python developer full time, so a lot of things have fallen out of my head in the interim. Google points me at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/, though, which is a lot like the thing I was remembering.